# how to use interfaces of the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

If I defined an interface in a base class and I'm calling that interface through a derived class, the only way that I found to use that base's class interface is by using "`using`" in the derived class. I'm not sure if it's a good practice. Here is a sample program

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class B 
{
public:
  void outB() { cout << "dim from B is " << dim_ << endl ; }
  B(int dim) : dim_(dim) {}
  ~B() {}
protected:
  int dim_;
};

template <class T>
class A : B<T>
{
public:
  using B<T>::dim_;
  using B<T>::outB;
  void outA() { cout << "dim from A is " << dim_ << endl ; }
  A(int dim) : B<T>(dim) {}
  ~A() {}
private:
};


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  shared_ptr<A<double> > ap(new A<double>(2));
  ap->outA();
  ap->outB();
  return 0;
}
```

If I take away the line `using B<T>::outB;` the program does not compile. http://ideone.com/x6gm0

The problem with using `using` all the time is that if I have a long chain of derived classes (for example if I extensively use adapter pattern), I have to write `using ...;` in each derived class for all of inherited interfaces.

What is a good practice to go around the repetition of `using` in each derived class to keep the interfaces of the base class?

Note, i'd like to avoid using `virtual`. I need performance from the code.

Comment: Early optimizations...are you sure you can't use virtual methods? Few pointer indirections may save you to introduce bugs hard to find and they'll make your code easier to read. **Are you really sure???***

Comment: those are two functions with different names, you are not using base class's function in derived class anyway.

Comment: @C-xC-t I wasn't sure how to phrase the title. But I meant calling outB from main. since ap pointer is of type A, shouldn't I be able to access interfaces of a class B, the class from which A derives, from main?

Comment: @Adriano, to be honest, I'm still learning C++ and I jumped over getting experience with virtual function. I use modern c++ and boost as guidance. So far, from what I hear, virtual functions can be avoided; sometimes by using CRTP. So i know what they are and cna read them but I try to have a style that avoids them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not declaring `class A: public B<T>` in which case you wont need the `using`? Now this works out of the box for *member functions* in the base class. To get access to the base class member variables, you either need to do what you are doing or access them via explicit call to `this` pointer i.e `this->dim_` instead of just `dim_`

Comment: thanks, I'm retarded. I need to configure snipmate or something like that. I'm sorry for dumb question. thanks to everyone for help and additional information.

Answer (score 1):

The `using` is only needed if the base class is a template. So you can check if you need the base class to be a template. But AFAIK you don't go around it, you just have to live with it.

Regarding virtual function calls: The performance impact is often overestimated. I recommend actually measuring the impact and then see if something needs to be done.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, performance penalty by `virtuals` should be the last thing you should worry.